# Can this be proved? S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$(A∩B)Δ(C∩D)=(AΔB)∩(CΔD)$$
I have been trying to prove this equation but I am not sure whether this can be done.

Comment: Hint: "Let $x \in \ldots$ Then...

Comment: Second hint: Choose $A = C = \{1\}$ and $B = D = \emptyset$. Then ...

Comment: @SeanRoberson i have tried using truth table to prove this but I was not able to do it

Comment: @LalitPathak Actually, a truth-table should work if you treat $\cap$ as a $\land$ and $\Delta$ as a $XOR$ ...

Comment: Third hint: If you cannot prove that an assumption holds, try to find a counterexample instead.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Counterexample: $A=B=C=\{ 1 \}$ , $D = \emptyset$